# ASP.NET MVC returning zipped file with FileResult is missing extension

Tags: asp.net-mvc, streaming, fileresult

I have a zipped file which I am trying to stream to client:

```
public FileResult GetFiles()
{
    return File("test.zip", "application/zip");
}
```

The file downloads but without the ".zip" extension.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could specify a download filename:

```
return File("test.zip", "application/zip", "test.zip");
```